# Sequence that is neither increasing nor decreasing yet has a limit of 2.

Tags: real-analysis

I am study for my final and looking over old quiz questions. I came across a questions that says given an example of a sequence which is neither increasing nor decreasing whose limit is 2.

I got the question wrong. Can someone give me an answer and explain how they got there?

Comment: I mean there is a rather trivial answer $a_n = 2.$ Other than that, I'd probably use something like $a_n = \frac{\sin(n+1)}{(n+1)} + 2.$

Comment: Hint:  try to make a sequence which alternates around $2$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan I'd argue that $a_n=2$ is both increasing and decreasing.

Comment: @DonThousand Good point, sorry I got mixed up with *strictly* increasing/decreasing.

Comment: Well, you just need a sequence that "gets close" to $2$.  There is utterly no reason it has to "grow" and get bigger and bigger as it gets close to $2$ or that it needs to shrink as it gets close to $2$.  It can get close to $2$ go over then go down go under and go up again.  It doesn't even have to *always* get *closer to $2$.  It' easy to think of some.  Say.... $1.9, 2.1, 1.99, 2.01, 1.999, 2.001, etc$ where each odd term is a tiny power of $10$ less than $2$ and each even term is a tiny power of $10$ more than $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Why "yet" in the title of your question? Is there some intuitive reason why a nonmonotonic sequence should not converge to $2$? Anyway, here is an example:

$$2.1,2.01,2.001,2.01,2.001,2.0001,2.001,2.0001,2.00001,2.0001,2.00001,2.000001,\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

You can find a decreasing sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n \to 2$ and an increasing sequence  $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $b_n \to 2$. Then the sequence
$$c_n=\{a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,a_3,b_3,...\}$$
is neither increasing nor decreasing but $c_n \to 2$. For example $a_n=2+1/n$ and $b_n=2-1/n$ do the trick. [image]